# LINQ Query To Join Two Tables and Select Most Recent Records from Table B corresponding to Table A

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have two tables. Table One contains a list of Areas, and Table Two contains a list of Samples, with each Sample row containing `Area_ID` as a Foreign Key.

I need to retrieve all the records in my Area table with only the most recent corresponding Sample Status.  I have this query, but it just returns one Area with the most recent sample from the Sample table:

```
var result = (
    from a in db.area
    join c in db.sample
    on a.location_id equals c.location_id

    select new 
    {
        name = a.location_name,
        status = c.sample_status,
        date = c.sample_date
    }).OrderByDescending(c => c.date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That's because you have FirstOrDefault() which only selects first one from the available collection or null if the collection is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution could be filtering your second `DbSet`:

```
 var result =  from a in db.area
               join c in db.sample.Where(s=>s.location_id==a.location_id).OrderByDescending(c => c.sample_date).Take(1)
               on a.location_id equals c.location_id 
               select new 
                    {
                         name = a.location_name,
                         status = c.sample_status,
                         date = c.sample_date
                    };
```

Another solution could be applying a [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx):

```
 var result =  from a in db.area
               join c in db.sample
               on a.location_id equals c.location_id into samples
               let sample=samples.OrderByDescending(c => c.sample_date).FirstOrDefault()
               select new 
                    {
                          name = a.location_name,
                          status = sample.sample_status,
                          date = sample.sample_date
                    };
```

If you use navigation properties could be even easier. Supposing you have a one to many relationship between `Area` and `Sample`:

```
var result =from a in db.area
            let sample= a.Samples.OrderByDescending(c => c.sample_date).FirstOrDefault()
            select new 
                    {
                          name = a.location_name,
                          status = sample.sample_status,
                          date = sample.sample_date
                    };
```

Comment: Group Join solution worked perfectly! So what is happening is, joining a and c into a new grouping of samples, and then filtering the samples grouping by date using FirstOrDefault? Great!

Comment: Speaking of the group join, this should also handle the case of Areas with no associated samples to display, as we need all areas displayed ("I need to retrieve all the records in my Area table with.."), one way to do that is to change the status and date fields to :

status = sample.sample_status == null ? "NA" : sample.sample_status,
date = "" + sample.sample_date

That's what I used in my case.